# How to add attributes to a request in a scrapy contract

Tags: python, scrapy

Scrapy contract fails if we are instantiating an Item or ItemLoader with the meta attribute or the Request() object passed from a previous parse method.

I was thinking of maybe overriding [ScrapesContract](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contracts/default.py#L77) to preprocess the request and load some dummy values in request.meta, not sure if that is good practice though.

I have seen the `pre_process` method in the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/contracts.html) (illustrated in the HasHeaderContract at the bottom) to get attributes from the request object, but I'm not sure if it can be used to set attributes.

EDIT: More details. Methods from an example crawler:

```
def parse_level_one(self, response):
   # populate loader
   return Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_level_two, meta={'loader': loader.load_item()})

def parse_level_two(self, response):
    """Parse product detail page

    @url http://example.com
    @scrapes some_field1 some_field2
    """
    loader = MyItemLoader(response.meta['loader'], response=response)
```

in the cli

```
$ scrapy check crawlername
Traceback... loader = MyItemLoader(response.meta['loader'], response=response)
KeyError: 'loader'
```

The idea that I am thinking about is this:

```
class LoadedScrapesContract(Contract):
    """ Contract to check presence of fields in scraped items
        @loadedscrapes page_name page_body
    """

    name = 'loadedscrapes'

    def pre_process(self, response):
        # MEDDLE WITH THE RESPONSE OBJECT HERE
        # TO ADD A META ATTRIBUTE TO RESPONSE,
        # LIKE AN EMPTY Item() or dict, JUST TO MAKE
        # THE ITEM LOADER INSTANTIATION PASS

    # this is same as ScrapesContract 
    def post_process(self, output):
        for x in output:
            if isinstance(x, BaseItem):
                for arg in self.args:
                    if not arg in x:
                        raise ContractFail("'%s' field is missing" % arg)
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproduceable example demonstrating the problem? thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I have added some details. For a reproducible example, add a contract to any parse method that instantiates an item or itemloader with the meta attribute of the Requests object.

Comment: try passing the itemloader itself, instead of the item: `meta={'loader':itemloader}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found for this, is to do the following rather than mucking up the contract

```
loader = MyItemLoader(response.meta.get('loader', MyItem()), response=response)
```

I prefer this method, but to stick the question, override [`adjust_request_args`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/contracts.html#scrapy.contracts.Contract.adjust_request_args)