# Scrapy contracts with multiple parse methods

Tags: python, unit-testing, scrapy, web-crawler, contracts

What's the best approach to write contracts for Scrapy spiders that have more than one method to parse the response?
I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368342/how-to-add-attributes-to-a-request-in-a-scrapy-contract) but it didn't sound very clear to me.

My current example: I have a method called `parse_product` that extracts the information on a page but I have more data that I need to extract for the same product in another page, so I `yield` a new request at the end of this method to make a new request and let the new callback extracts theses fields and returns the item.

The problem is that if I write a contract for the second method, it will fail because it doesn't have the meta attribute (containing the item with most of the fields). If I write a contract for the first method, I can't check if it returns the fields, because it returns a new request, instead of the item.

```
def parse_product(self, response):
    il = ItemLoader(item=ProductItem(), response=response)
    # populate the item in here

    # yield the new request sending the ItemLoader to another callback
    yield scrapy.Request(new_url, callback=self.parse_images, meta={'item': il})

def parse_images(self, response):
     """
     @url http://foo.bar
     @returns items 1 1
     @scrapes field1 field2 field3
     """
     il = response.request.meta['item']
     # extract the new fields and add them to the item in here

     yield il.load_item()
```

In the example, I put the contract in the second method, but it gave me a `KeyError` exception on `response.request.meta['item']`, also, the fields `field1` and `field2` are populated in the first method.

Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Did you finally found a solution to this problem ?

Comment: No I didn't, eventually I gave up on using contracts, as pointed for Elias in the answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Frankly, I don't use Scrapy contracts and I don't really recommend anyone to use them either. They have [many issues](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1918) and [someday may be removed from Scrapy](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1777#issuecomment-184272838).

In practice, I haven't had much luck using unit tests for spiders.

For testing spiders during development, I'd enable the cache and then re-run the spider as many times as needed to get the scraping right.

For regression bugs, I had better luck using item pipelines (or spider middlewares) that do validation on-the-fly (there is only so much you can catch in early testing anyway). It's also a good idea to have some strategies for recovering.

And for maintaining a healthy codebase, I'd be constantly moving library-like code out from the spider itself to make it more testable.

Sorry if this isn't the answer you're looking for.

Comment: It wasn't exactly the answer I was looking for but it did help me a lot, maybe more than the actual answer (if it exists). Thank you.